# CSS :hover doesn't change the colour element

Tags: sass

I am creating a side navigation panel and I can't seem to figure out how to change colour of the text in link when I hover over it. The background colour changes. It actually worked before I added the animation but I wouldn't want to pass out on the animation.

```
.sidenav-navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;

  .sidenav-navigation-items {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;

  .sidenav-navigation-link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 3rem;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;

    .sidenav-navigation-link-icon {
      font-size: 22px;
      width: 2rem;
      min-width: 2rem;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .sidenav-navigation-link-text {
      text-align: center;
      margin-right: 0.5rem;
      animation:fadeIn 0.7s;
      }
    }
  }
}
.sidenav-navigation-items:hover{
  .sidenav-navigation-link {
    transition: all .1s ease;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
  0%{opacity:0;}
  50%{opacity:50%;}
  100%{opacity:100%;}
}
```

Comment: Show your HTML too

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Probably white color style has higher priority due to more specific rules. Try to use `!important` rule with lower prio style.

```css
.sidenav-navigation-items:hover{
  .sidenav-navigation-link {
    transition: all .1s ease;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    background-color: white;
    color: black !important;
  }
}
```

Other option may be changing the way of rules nesting to below:

```css
.sidenav-navigation {
  .sidenav-navigation-items {
    .sidenav-navigation-link {
      color: white;
    }
    &:hover {
      .sidenav-navigation-link {
        color: black;
      }
    }
  }
}
```